# How do I update input values with db values after a select OnChange with idealforms?

Tags: php, jquery, forms, select, input

I'm using idealforms from elclanrs and I have a select which is filled from a database. OnChange I want to update the value of the input fields with information from the database. In this case, firstname, lastname. I tried it with AJAX but that didn't work out because when the form values where getting renewed, the whole idealforms makeup of the form vanishes.

I looked through stackoverflow and saw it was a fairly common problem but I still can't seem to work it out. I used [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5457739/change-value-of-input-onchange) and it didn't work, maybe because I placed it in the wrong order?

This is my code:

```
    <form id="my-form" action="EditAccountHandler.php" method="post">

        <?php
        include 'conn/dbConnect.php';

        echo '<div><label>Gebruikers</label><select id="gebruiker" selected="$sUsername" name="selectedUser" onchange="updateInput(this.value)">';

$sqEditUser = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM account a, persoon p WHERE a.idSuper = p.idUser", $con);

        while($row = mysql_fetch_array($sqEditUser))
                {
                     $iIdUser = $row['idUser'];
                     $sFirstname = $row['Voornaam'];
                     $sLastname = $row['Achternaam'];
                     $sUsername = "{$sLastname}, {$sFirstname}";

                     echo "<option value='$iIdUser'>$sUsername</option>";
                }

        echo "</select></div>";
        ?>
        <script>
        function updateInput(<?= json_encode($sFirstname); ?>)
        {
        document.getElementById("naam").value = <?php echo json_encode($sFirstname); ?>;
        }
        </script>
                    <div><label>Voornaam</label><input id="naam" name="naam" type="text"/></div>
                   <div><label>Achternaam</label><input id="anaam" name="anaam" type="text"/></div>
              <div>     
                <button id="reset" type="button">Reset</button>
                <button type="submit">Wijzigen</button>
              </div>
            </form>
```

This is what I'm trying to achieve:
[Example picture](http://tinypic.com/r/33z92k7/6)

I'm not sure about what I am doing wrong. Can yo guys help me?

**Edit**
Removed code that was double in comparison with the first codesnippet.
Added echo
Removed action="EditAccountHandler.php"
Added idealforms validation code
Replaced with final code

```
<div id="main">

                <h3>Wijzig Account</h3><br />
                <form id="myselect" action="" method="post">
                <div>
                <label>Gebruikers</label><select id="gebruiker" selected="$sUsername" name="selectedUser" onchange="this.form.submit()">
                <?php
                include 'conn/dbConnect.php';

                $sqUser = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM account a, persoon p WHERE a.idSuper = p.idUser", $con);

                    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($sqUser))
                    {
                         $iIdUser = $row['idUser'];
                         $sFirstname = $row['Voornaam'];
                         $sLastname = $row['Achternaam'];
                         $sUsername = "{$sLastname}, {$sFirstname}";

                         echo "<option value='$iIdUser'>$sUsername</option>";
                    }
                ?>
                </select>
                </div>
                </form>

                <script>
                var options = { onFail: function(){alert('Selecteer een persoon')}};
                var $myform1 = $('#myselect').idealforms(options).data('idealforms');
                $myform1.focusFirst();
                </script>   

                <?php
                    if(!empty($_POST['selectedUser']))
                    {
                        $sqGetUser = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM persoon WHERE idUser = '$_POST[selectedUser]'", $con);      
                        while($row = mysql_fetch_array($sqGetUser))
                        {
                             $sFname = $row['Voornaam'];
                             $sLname = $row['Achternaam'];
                        }
                ?>

                    <form id="my-form" action="EditAccountHandler.php" method="post">
                    <div><label>Voornaam</label><input id="naam" name="naam" value="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($sFname); ?>" type="text"/></div>
                    <div><label>Achternaam</label><input id="anaam" name="anaam" value="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($sLname); ?>" type="text"/></div>
                    <div>
                        <label>Rechten</label>
                        <label><input type="radio" name="rechten" value="Administrator"/>Administrator</label>
                        <label><input type="radio" name="rechten" value="Contentmanager"/>Contentmanager</label>
                        <label><input type="radio" name="rechten" value="Administratie"/>Administratie</label>
                        <label><input type="radio" name="rechten" value="Medewerker"/>Medewerker</label>
                        <label><input type="radio" name="rechten" value="Klant" checked/>Klant</label>
                        <label><input type="radio" name="rechten" value="Gast"/>Gast</label>
                        <label><input type="radio" name="rechten" value="MedeKlant"/>MedeKlant</label>
                    </div>
                    <div>   
                        <button id="reset" type="button">Reset</button>
                        <button type="submit">Wijzigen</button>
                    </div>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
<script>

var options = 
{
    onFail: function() 
    {
      alert( 'Vul alle velden correct in.' )
    },
    inputs: 
    {               
        'anaam': 
        {
        filters: 'required name',

        },

        'naam': 
        {
        filters: 'required name',
        },
    }
};

 var $myform = $('#my-form').idealforms(options).data('idealforms');

  $('#reset').click(function(){ $myform.reset().fresh().focusFirst() });
  $myform.focusFirst();
</script>
<?php
}
?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are messing client code with server code.

Once the onChange event is fired, you have to reload the page for example onChange="this.form.submit()" and you verify if(!empty($_POST["selectedUser"])) then you fill the fields of the form with the data you can obtain with a new SQL query, where id = $_POST["selectedUser"].

In this case you don't need the updateuser function.

If you use AJAX, you would need the updateuser function, but you have got to get rid of the json_encode methods which execute on server, and with ajax everything is in the client part. It would be simply: "function updateuser(id)".

You can use jquery to do the ajax call to get the info, and then you fill the form fields.

EDIT:

Examining the new code you provide. I see one error, you are using htmlspecialchars function but you are not echoing it, ;-). You should use "echo ...".

For the form, you should use "this.form.submit()" if you are inside the form labels.
If you use jquery it would be something like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

$("#selectedUser").change(function()
{
    if(this.form.elements['selectedUser'].value!="")
    {
        this.form.submit();
    }
});
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks for your response :). I tried it with the onChange and $_POST but it doesn't fill the values. Also after I select a user the dropdownlist doesn't dissapear. It just stays there hanging. I wanted to add code to show you how I did it but I couldn't in comments. Should I put that in an answer?

Comment: @user2154002 the best thing is you add/modify the code, even the question. As I say you have to realize what it's executed in the client side and what in the server, because your code gives the impression you are mixing things.

Comment: Ok, I see the mistake, it is a little thing, you are not echoing the result from the query, I have written this in my answer.

Comment: This works with the echoing and the .submit() but only at the moment I remove the element action="EditAccountHanlder.php" from form. Which is logical because I use: this.form.submit(). That also overrides the funtionality of elclanrs idealforms, who submits the form only if the form can be validated. Is there another method for that? And what exactly do you mean with 'if you are inside the labels' :)?

Comment: I mean that you can use "this.form" if you execute any code that is inside the beginning of "<form>" and the end tag "</form>". I don't understand right now what could fail, because you have not provided any code about elclanrs idealforms.

Comment: added idealforms code, jquery.idealforms.js is available here: [link]https://github.com/elclanrs/jq-idealforms/blob/master/js/min/jquery.idealforms.js [/link]. The difference with mine is that I changed the errormessages into another language and with th onSuccess function I removed the 'Thank you' alert. The rest is the same.

Comment: If the textboxes where you enter the name, surname, are not used until you choose the user, I would not show them before you select the user, so the brackets of "if(!empty($_POST['selectedUser']))" would end after the idealforms script. Another solution would be to have two forms, one for the select and another for the rest, you can have more than one form in a page (except in .NET).

Comment: It works perfectly!! Thank you so much for your time and help :):)!! Have a nice 'long' weekend and easter :)!