# How to change style using javascript?

Tags: javascript

```html
<div class="club_member">
<input type="text" size="5" onclick="this.value=''" name="scienceClub" value="2">
</div>
```

How can I use a simple javascript command to change the value to "0" and place a 'disable=""' in the input style?

Comment: neither `value` nor `disabled` are styles, they are attributes or properties of the `input` element.

Comment: Duplicate to: [How to disable an input type=text?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2874688/1960455) and [Change value of input onchange?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5457739/1960455)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `object.value` to set the value and `object.disabled` to disable the input in Javascript.

**Demo:**

```js
document.getElementById("button").addEventListener("click", function(){  // I have added a sample button for testing
  
  var inputElementObject = document.getElementById("input");  // get the input element object
  
  inputElementObject.value = "0";  // set the value
  inputElementObject.disabled = true;  // set the disabled property
  
});
```

```html
<div class="club_member">
  
  <!-- set an ID for the input element -->
  <input type="text" size="5" onclick="this.value=''" name="scienceClub" value="2" id="input">
  
  <button id="button">Click me!</button>
  
</div>
```

[Check out how to set the properties for `<input>` here on MDN.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/HTMLInputElement)

Comment: I like the idea of you putting it in a button. And thank you so much. I didn't put an id to the input. Instead I did this.
document.getElementsByName("scienceClub")[0].value = "0";
document.getElementsByName("scienceClub")[0].disabled = false;

Comment: @warholzz116 Thank you. I figured it would be helpful for the demo. :) If you found this answer good enough, please mark it as accepted.

Answer (score 1):

First set id in your control like this

```
<input type="text" id="myControl" size="5" onclick="this.value=''" name="scienceClub" value="2">
```

Then Try like this in script

```
var control=document.getElementById("myControl");
control.value=0;
control.setAttribute("disabled", true);
```

Comment: Thank you. But instead of setting an id, I've used getElementsbyName("scienceClub")[0];

Answer (score 0):

The below snippet demonstrates how to change the value and disable the input using strictly JavaScript.

```js
document.getElementById("input").value = "0";
document.getElementById("input").disabled = true;
```

```html
<div class="club_member">
  <input type="text" size="5" onclick="this.value=''" name="scienceClub" value="2" id="input">
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Using the same code as you posted. you just have to change its value and it gets disabled.

```html
 <div class="club_member">
 <input type="text" id='something' size="5" onclick="this.value='0'; this.setAttribute('disabled','true');" name="scienceClub" value="2">
 </div>
```

```html
 <div class="club_member">
 <input type="text" id='something' size="5" onclick='this.value="0"' name="scienceClub" value="2">
 <button onclick="document.getElementById('something').setAttribute('disabled','true');"> Lock the value </button>
 </div>
```